# Viewing browser Files System

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how I can use JavaScript to view a page's File System [File System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uIDV.png) and query if a specific file exists. Does anyone know of a way to do this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why would you be checking for specific file that's loaded? It makes more sense to check for specific functionality which will be unlinked to the file name.

Comment: @VLAZ I am trying to detect if something like Tampermonkey has installed a script. I notice that it says "userscript.html" and I want to check if that is ever loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally this isn't something you would do with JavaScript because it is a front-end language. However, you could potentially use AJAX to send a request for a file and based on the response you could determine if it exists or not.

There are a few limitations though. Firstly, you will need to know exactly what files you are looking for. You won't be able to get folders and/or lists of files. Secondly, this will only work for files on the same domain as the your page.

```
try {
    fetch("file_name.txt").then(r => {
        if(r.status == 200) {
            return "File Found";
        } else {
            return "No File";
        }
    }).then(d => console.log(d));
} catch(e) {
    console.log("No File", e);
}
```